# Is it necessary to mock all and every dependency in Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to create a unit test for an ASP.NET that has the following constructor definition (filled with Ninject when running the real application):

```
    public OrderController(IViewModelFactory modelFactory, INewsRepository repository, ILoggedUserHelper loggedUserHelper,
        IDelegateHelper delegateHelper, ICustomerContextWrapper customerContext) {
        this.factory = modelFactory;
        this.loggedUserHelper = loggedUserHelper;
        this.delegateHelper = delegateHelper;
        this.customerContext = customerContext;
    }
```

I want to test the methods inside the **OrderController** class, but in order to isolate it, I have to mock all and every of those dependencies, which becomes outright ridiculous (having to also mock subdependencies probably).

In this case, which is the best practice to Unit Test this class?

Comment: Just mock all four injected dependencies. If you are not using Moq, it should make mocking that much easier.

Comment: I'm using Moq to Mock those dependencies (Or at least that was my intention)

Comment: What makes mocking four dependancies that ridiculous our of interest? Presumably you only need to set up one or two methods on each of the mocked objects?

Comment: But aren't implementation details leaked in the test if I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have to provide *test doubles* for all dependencies, not necessarily mocks.

Luckily,this is the 21st century and there are tools to make the job easier for us. You can use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) to create an instance of `OrderController` and inject mocks as necessary.

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
var orderController = fixture.Create<OrderController>();
```

Which, basically, is equivalent to:

```
var factory = new Mock<IViewModelFactory>();
var repository = new Mock<INewsRepository>();
var delegateHelper = new Mock<IDelegateHelper >();
var customerContext = new Mock<ICustomerContextWrapper >();

var orderController = new OrderController(factory.Object, repository.Object, delegateHelper.Object, customerContext.Object);
```

If those dependencies depend on other types, those will be setup as well. AutoFixture with the `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` customization will build an entire graph of dependencies.

If you need access to, say, the repository mock, so you can do some additional setups or assertions on it later, you can *freeze* it. Freezing a type will make the `fixture` container contain only one instance of that type, e.g.:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
var repositoryMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<INewsRepository>>();
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Retrieve()).Returns(1);

//the frozen instance will be injected here
var orderController = fixture.Create<OrderController>(); 

repositoryMock.Verify(x => x.Retrieve(), Times.Once);
```

I've used Moq in these examples, but AutoFixture also integrates with NSubstitute, RhinoMock and Foq.

Disclosure: I'm one of the project's contributors

Comment: That's interesting, can I then customize those autogenerated mocks in case I need it? What do method calls/properties/whatever to those mocks return?

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Yes you can, using `Freeze`. I've added an example to my post, on how to do additional setups. This customization will setup all mock's members as such: `mockObject.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(fixture.Create<int>())`. Basically, the fixture will call itself recursively until the whole graph of dependencies is created.

Comment: Check the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) (it's a bit outdated though, but still useful). Also, if you don't want autofixture to automatically setup the mocks for you, you can use the `AutoMoqCustomization` customization instead which simply injects shiny brand new mocks.

Comment: I have a final theoretical question. When you test and define mocks behaviour on TDD, aren't you partially leaking the innards of the method you want to test or how it should behave instead of checking the in/out of the function? Just asking.

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez  That's a brilliant question, one I've asked myself many times. TDD is all about focusing on the external behaviour and usage of a unit of code, but having to inject and configure test doubles creates a huge paradox. Let me know if you find a satisfying answer :)

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Some similar questions, worth a reading: [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/198453/is-there-a-point-to-unit-tests-that-stub-and-mock-everything-public), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/234024/unit-testing-behaviours-without-coupling-to-implementation-details), [3](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't.  The different concepts of test object implementations you can use are known as Test Doubles.  Mocks are just one type of Test Double as defined by Gerard Meszaros in [his book](http://xunitpatterns.com/):

- **Dummy** objects are passed around but never actually used. Usually they are just used to fill parameter lists.
- **Fake** objects actually have working implementations, but usually take some shortcut which makes them not suitable for production (an InMemoryTestDatabase is a good example).
- **Stubs** provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the test.
- **Spies** are stubs that also record some information based on how they were called. One form of this might be an email service that records how many messages it was sent.
- **Mocks** are pre-programmed with expectations which form a specification of the calls they are expected to receive. They can throw an exception if they receive a call they don't expect and are checked during verification to ensure they got all the calls they were expecting.

You only need to give as many stubs, fakes and dummies as required for your test to pass.

Dummies take very little work to generate and may be enough to cover your scenario.  An example would be a constructor that takes an IEmailer and an ILogWriter.  If you're only testing the Log method, you only need to provide enough of an implementation of IEmailer in order for the test to not throw Argument exceptions.

Also, regarding your point about sub-dependencies... Moq will take care of that for you, because Moq implementations of your interface won't take dependencies.